# At what point is the line $y = mx + b$ tangent to $y = \sin (mx + b)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I was playing around on [Desmos](https://desmos.com) to investigate the visual relationship between $y = mx + b$ and $y = \frac{x + m}{b}$. I noticed that the effect of $m$ and $b$ on these two equations were opposite: scaling $m$ increases the slope of $y = mx + b$ while shifting $y = \frac{m + x}{b}$ from left to right, while scaling $b$ does the inverse.

Out of curiosity, I applied the sine function to each of these equations and discovered that they respond similarly: scaling $m$ and $b$ contracts or shifts the two waves. I also noticed that the lines were tangent to their respective sine wave, shifting and sloping to, on a visual level, remain tangent to the same location on the wave (e.g., decreasing $b$ causes both the line $y = mx + b$ and its corresponding sine wave $y = \sin (mx + b)$ to visually move together, with the line appearing to "move" with the same wavefront).

I'm wondering how to calculate exactly where the line $y = mx + b$ is tangent to $y = \sin (mx + b)$.

Comment: Indeed, you are looking for values $b,m$ in which $\cos(mx+b)=1$.

Comment: Can you differentiate both equations and then set them equal to each other? I have a feeling your question should be tagged algebra-precalculus.

Answer (score 3):

We'll restrict our analysis to the reals throughout.

Note that functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are tangent at point $x=c$ when
$$f(c)=g(c)\\f'(c)=g'(c).$$

---

In your case, for $f(x)\equiv mx+b,g(x)\equiv \sin(mx+b),$ these equations are
$$mc+b=\sin(mc+b)\quad (1)\\
m=m\cos(mc+b)\quad (2).$$

Lemma: Convince yourself that $f_1(u)\equiv u,g_1(u)\equiv \sin u$ uniquely intersect at a tangency point $u=0$ (you can show this my applying the mean value theorem to $f_1-g_1$, for instance).

By this lemma, $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold if and only if $mc+b=0$. Consider two cases:

Case 1: $m=0.$ Then we must have $b=0$; that is, $f,g$ are are identically zero functions (and hence tangent at all points).

Case 2: $m\neq 0$. Then for any $m,b$, tangency occurs uniquely at $c=-b/m.$

Answer (score 0):

$y=x$ is tangent to $y=\sin x$  at $x = 0$

Replacing $x$ with $mx$ will apply the same horizontal compression to both functions.

and replacing $mx$ with  $m(x-a)$ will apply the same lateral translation ($a$ units to the right).